# Create doc for rails, plugins, app in a single file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rdoc

I was wondering what the best option for generating doc for rails, its plugin and the app in one single file that I can navigate.
I've been using rdoc but that creates multiple files, yard is too slow and hanna gets stuck at random places.
Any help?

Comment: Also, in hanna you can go into that file that's erroring and fix the `#empty?` check so it also checks for `nil`. (I presume you're getting the same error I am.)

Answer (score 0):

If you truly want just the one file, maybe [`rocco`](http://rtomayko.github.com/rocco/) would work well for you: